# Rindler coordinates diagram in the rest frame of accelerating observer

Tags: special-relativity, acceleration, coordinate-systems

The Rindler coordinates are calculated in an inertial rest frame, from which the worldlines of accelerating observers are determined.

How does this coordinate space look like in the frame of an accelerating observer?
I was able to find a YT video where the lecturer shows the image below, but I was not able to find more information regarding it.

[image]

Comment: No, the Rindler coordinates are the coordinates in the rest frame of the accelerating observer. Well, unles you and I mean something very different by _Rindler coordinates_.

Comment: @JohnRennie I'm still studying this so I've probably muddled it up, but I took it to understand that Rinder coordinates as those that correspond to the rest frame of the acc. observer, but the diagram that we usually see (the one with hyberbolae) is wrt. a fixed inertial observer. Please correct me if I'm wrong.

Answer (score 1):

> How does this coordinate space look like in the frame of an accelerating observer?

It is a rectilinear grid in the frame of the accelerating observer, by definition.

The image that you show is the Minkowski coordinate grid lines displayed in the Rindler frame.

Comment: SO the diagram which we usually see is the Rindler coordinatization of Minkowski space? Could you please provide some resources to read more about Minkowski coordinate grid lines displayed in the Rindler frame?

Comment: @AlanWhitteaker I don't have a reference for the plots. You can just take the coordinate transformation and plot the lines. see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rindler_coordinates